# Mark handout slides in beamer package

Tags: beamer

For my presentation I am using the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) package. I added frames that include my personal notes that only appear when I am compiling with the handout-option.

On this handout I would like to include a sign on each slide that indicates whether it is being shown in the presentation (when compiled with the presentation mode) or not so that I have a quick overview when I am looking at my printed handout. Such a sign could be a bold "B" in the top right corner.

How do I implement this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find a solution when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the following approach with my lecture notes. Create a command called `\markslide`, which uses some symbol of your choice. Then, place `\only<0|handout:N>{\markslide}` at the beginning of `\frametitle{}`. The first `0` tells beamer to hide the contents of `\only{}` from beamer mode, while the `handout:N` part tells beamer to display the contents of `\only{}` on slide #N within a frame.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\markslide}{\textreferencemark} % requires textcomp package

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\only<0|handout:2>{\markslide}Title}
\only<1|handout:1>{%
Stuff that appears in both beamer and handout mode
}
\only<0|handout:2>{%
Stuff that appears only in handout mode
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm! For some reason I couldn't adapt it into my existing presentation such that I had to build it from scratch again; eventually it worked out though.