# How to make a handout with underslide data?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, powerpoint, handout

Is there any possibility to make handout from beamer presentation with underslide data (notes) like in PowerPoint or simillar ShitWin stuff?

Thank you help.

[image: Needed output]

Comment: Windows is shit, but you want to emulate a feature of PowerPoint? That's not Windows, of course, but the software company is said to be the same.

Comment: @Vojta Please see this link  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250544/197451 and  also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214227/197451 as well as  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35028/197451